# XMPPFramework - 'didReceiveMessage' called two times when message is received

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

Whenever I receive any new messages, these two methods gets called two times.

```
- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
```

I am sending request to server to get my roster list with the following code.

```
NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:@"jabber:iq:roster"];
XMPPIQ *iq = [XMPPIQ iq];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"buddyRequest"];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"54.186.107.171"];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"get"];
[iq addChild:query];
[self.xmppStream sendElement:iq];
```

Could somebody point out to me where the problem might lie?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you call only once the first block of code? When your delegate methods are called, are the object the same (the pointers especially)?

Comment: Thank you for replay.yes. I am cal only once. Well, When I am sending message from spark to my application DidReciveMessage Called 2 times. So my tableview shows two same message in my application.

Comment: How many time u set the delegate of XMPPStream?

Comment: [xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

I have typed this line twice.

Comment: Thank you. My issue has been solved. Actually, for second line I have typed XMPPStream insted of xmpproster. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you set the delegate to XMPPStream twice.Remove one and check.Then also u got two response , check the xmppstream object value.is both are different , surely you set twice.